# Signal return has a complex path, is there a remedy?

Tags: routing

In picture:

[image]

I have three different PCB that has connected as in picture above:

1. Power supply: +12V
2. Power amifier
3. Signal generator.

Note OpAmps negative rails are grounded.

The power amp internal schmatic (I've modeled it on the above picture but I've also puted here if I did something wrong):
[image: class d]

These three PCB has been connected by wire.

The signal is generated on the  left side called signal generator. The signal will go through the power amplifier, then the power supply and return to the signal generator.

I think the return path is not straitforward, is there any solution to make it more confined and more EMC EMC and noise robust?

Comment: where is the power amp output? ... why does the signal travel through the power supply?

Comment: Is this a layout routing question? Put in power planes in the PCB.

Comment: This is why you use planes.

Comment: @jsotola You mean my routing on the picture is wrong? Then what is the corrected one?

Comment: @Dejvid_no1 The PCB's are fixed but I want to wiring them together although the signal generator is desined by me.

Comment: @DKNguyen You mean the schmatic is right but we need power plane to ease the pathes? Though this is impossible since they are seprate module.

Comment: @jsotola Power amp output is differential. Because signal generator buffer produces signal with power delivered from power supply.

Comment: Having a plane underneath means the return current automatically travels underneath the trace for the smallest possible loop area.

Comment: @DKNguyen Unfortiunately they are separate pcb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way and the only way is to use differential driver in sign gen stage. Though the grounded pin of power amp input can cause a problem of short circuit in the new situation. but you can simulate it, maybe work or you need to remove the ground from input pin of power amp, which force you to have two wire carrying the sig gen signal.

Other than differential. you can seprate the source of power amp from signal generator. I'm not sure but maybe different ground can generate hummmm on the signal. but can simplify the the signal path.